# React - Unhandled Error Event on react.render()

Tags: javascript, gulp, reactjs

I've seem to got a problem compiling my JSX files to JS when I run gulp.

Gulp Dependencies:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserify  = require('browserify');
var babelify    = require('babelify');
var source      = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var uglify      = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename      = require('gulp-rename');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
```

I thought that babelify would compile my JSX for me and I wouldn't have to worry about that.

I've then got my build files:

```
gulp.task('build', function () {
  return browserify({
    entries: 'app.js',
    extensions: ['.jsx'],
    debug: true
  })
  .transform(babelify)
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('compress', function() {
  return gulp.src('./dist/bundle.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', function(cb) {
  runSequence('build','compress', cb);
});
```

I seem to be getting the error on my app.js file where I add my first component.

Appreciate the help in advanced.

**** UPDATE ****

This is the error that I get once running gulp:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
SyntaxError: /Users/maxlynn/Documents/childcare-army/app.js: Unexpected token (6:4)
  4 | 
  5 | React.render(
> 6 |     <AppRoot />,
    |     ^
  7 |     document.getElementById('app-root')
  8 | );
```

Comment: We can't really help you much without any information about the error. What makes you think it has anything to do with JSX?

Comment: I've just added the error message im getting in my terminal. Not going to lie im new to react. Just trying to set up a play about environment. However I've read on different posts about this error that its due to the jsx not being compiled properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you recently installed babelify you need to pass some additional configuration to the transform call since Babel 6.x no longer ships with default presets enabled.

In order to be able to transpile JSX you need to enable the `react` preset.

```
npm install babel-preset-react babel-preset-es2015 --save

.transform('babelify', { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] })
```

Comment: You seem to be on the right path but I get this error now: Couldn't find preset "es2015"

Comment: Yeah, I revised the answer just before your comment.

Comment: Thats great. Seems to be working fine now. This feels like a step backwards for babel. Wonder why they choose to do it that way. I hope your answer helps others. Thanks